# Android Studio doesn't include .aar library when running app (Shift+F10), it does for Make

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, apk

I'm writing an application which uses a library contained in .aar file. The archive contains .so files. The .aar file is added as a dependency. When I click Build -> Make Project everything is OK, I get 11 MB APK which contains the .so files. But when I click Run then a different APK is being built. It's only 6 MB and doesn't contain .so libraries so it crashes with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

In the build log I see:

```
> Task :app:packageDebug
There are no .so files available to package in the APK for armeabi-v7a.
```